# Next.js Firebase Hosting 404 error on all except index.html

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I've built a nextjs app, with `npm run build && npm run export` and deployed to firebase using `firebase deploy` command. Prior to that, I've used `firebase init` in my project folder with just using the default options eg. not a single page application.

After I go and visit my project in firebase provided url however, I see the home page which is index.html, but whenever I use any other slug it throws a 404. Why this is happening ? I`ve included my firebase.json file, in case it might help.

**firebase.json**

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the rules you have Firebase Hosting serves the exact file that the user requested.

To rewrite other/all URLs to your `index.html`, you'll need to add a [rewrite rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) to your `firebase.json`. A typical rewrite rule for single-page applications may look like this:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this actually is not spa, do you know what should be done in case of a multiple page webapp built on nextjs ?

Comment: Ah, that's a rewrite to Cloud Functions or Cloud Run. If you scroll a bit down on the documentation link I provided, there are examples of that too.

Comment: Hey @MelihAlan Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I did but I realized I'm doing it all wrong from the start! Because NextJs is a SSR framework all the routes (pages) are to be rendered in the server, that's why I've uploaded a file called server.js, which includes one cloud function (runs in the firestore cloud functions) that handles all the routing. That solved the problem. I`m new at this, so I couldn't understand the documentation you're referring to, if this is the same as your answer, let me know so that I can accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Same thing indeed: your `server.js` serves the same function as `index.js` in a regular Cloud Fuctions/Express app.

Comment: I had the same issue when deploying my Quasar app on Firebase. In addition to the "rewrites" above i needed to add "cleanUrls": true in my firebase.json.

Answer (score 22):

For everybody that wants to deploy a statically exported Next.js app to Firebase hosting:

You would have to add "cleanUrls": true to the hosting configuration in firebase.json like so:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Without the "cleanUrls" configuration, the user would have to navigate to
https://example.com/login.html so that Next.js routes to the login page for example. With the parameter, a web request to https://example.com/login would work.

Comment: worked for me on a statically generated/exported Next.js app. Thanks!

Comment: This had me going round in circles. Thank you!

Comment: I wished we could have 2 accepted answers!

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is still looking for this, this is what fixed it for me:

I used dynamicLinks as stated [in the firebase hosting docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) for the rewrites like so in my `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/**", 
        "dynamicLinks": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This should allow dynamicLinks to start at ("https://CUSTOM_DOMAIN/{dynamicLink}").

Comment: This works in 2022 for Next.js

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is coming across this issue while deploying a NextJS app with getServerSideProps using Firebase's experimental webframeworks (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs_) I found my answer here: https://dev.to/rowaxl/what-i-struggled-with-next-js-using-firebase-hosting-and-enable-ssr-4e67

Instead of redirecting `**` to `/index.html` I had to point it to the server which is the cloud function that was generated by `firebase deploy`

Here is my firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "my-site",
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    },
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/auth/**",
        "function": "authFunction"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssrmysite"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me adding all the routes under rewrites under firebase.json file worked. Sample below.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/app/**",
        "destination": "/app/[id].html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/app/*/chat",
        "destination": "/app/[id]/chat.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you tried to deploy using experiments enable. I would suggest you try a normal deployment.

Remove `.firebase` folder and `firebase.json` and turn off experiments. Also delete the exiting cloud function.

```
firebase experiments:disable webframeworks #run to turn off experiments
```

Use these steps to deploy your application: https://github.com/milon27/next-js-portfolio

You can also refer to this video: https://youtu.be/PXqXOxr-LMg