# Nextjs on firebase hosting returns 404 on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-hosting

I've searched the documentation, and I can't seem to figure out why if you refresh the working page on firebase hosting, it'll throw a 404. The site works perfectly unless you try to directly access a page, or if you refresh the page (my guess is there's a disparity between the client browser state and the server state). Any ideas?

The site: [rockgodstudios.com](https://rockgodstudios.com)

Comment: The closest thing I've found is the cleanUrl option in firebase.js, but my deploy still isn't working. Maybe it takes a while for the deploy to carry over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was cleanUrls. Like a dummy, I had it *outside* of the `hosting` JSON. Moving it correctly fixed my issue. Posting for anybody in the future that has this issue.

Comment: Its not working for me. Can you help? I added `"cleanUrls": true` but it doesn't work. http://example.com/test.html works fine but http://example.com/test is not working. Its working fine on localhost. I'm using firebase hosting to deploy my react/next app.

Comment: Post an answer and I'll take a look. :)

Answer (score 2):

**I fix this issue by using dynamicLinks :-**

**Create custom domain Dynamic Links**

You can use rewrites to create custom domain Dynamic Links. Visit the Dynamic Links documentation for detailed information about [setting up a custom domain for Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains#priority_order). write this below code inside `firebase.json` file .

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/**", 
        "dynamicLinks": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the help of this other issue:

[Next JS on Firebase Hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66423932/next-js-firebase-hosting-404-error-on-all-except-index-html)

Although this makes that every time you refresh on any page you're redirected to the "Home" page. In my case this was ok.